# MVC3 Areas routing conflict

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, exception, asp.net-mvc-routing

Question: i want my route to be like that

/admin/main/category/1 -> 1 == ?page=1
i don't want page=1 to be seen

My Controller

```
public class MainController : BaseController
{
    private const int PageSize = 5; //pager view size

    [Inject]
    public ICategoryRepository CategoryRepository { get; set; }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Category(int page)
    {
        //int pageIndex = page.HasValue ? page.Value : 1;
        int pageIndex = page != 0 ? page : 1; 
        return View("Category", CategoryViewModelFactory(pageIndex));
    }

    /*
     *Helper: private instance/static methods
     ======================================================================*/
    private CategoryViewModel CategoryViewModelFactory(int pageIndex) //generate viewmodel category result on pager request
    {
        return new CategoryViewModel
        {
            Categories = CategoryRepository.GetActiveCategoriesListDescending().ToPagedList(pageIndex, PageSize)
        };
    }
}



  public class AdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
  {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get
            {
                return "admin";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRouteLowercase(
                "AdminCategoryListView", 
                "admin/{controller}/{action}/{page}",
                new { controller = "Category", action = "Category", page = "1" },
                new { id = @"\d+" },
                new[] { "WebUI.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
            );
        }
    }

My Exception:
```

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'page'
>   of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Category(Int32)' in
>   'WebUI.Areas.Admin.Controllers.MainController'. An optional parameter
>   must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an
>   optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that in your Admin area route registration you have defined the `{page}` route token instead of `{id}` which is generated by default:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Admin_default",
        "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{page}",
        new { action = "Index", page = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Now when you are generating links make sure you specify this parameter:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "go to page 5",                         // linkText
    "category",                             // actionName
    "main",                                 // controllerName
    new { area = "admin", page = "5" },     // routeValues
    null                                    // htmlAttributes
)
```

will emit:

```
<a href="/Admin/main/category/5">go to page 5</a>
```

and when this url is requested the Category action will be invoked and passed `page=5` parameter.

Comment: +1 thank you that's worked, but can i have more than one "route registration"?

Comment: You can have any number of route registrations. You just need to ensure that they are not conflicting and the routing engine is able to always disambiguate between then. For example if you have the following 2 urls: `Admin/{controller}/{action}/{page}`  and `Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}`, give an url like `/admin/main/category/5` the routing engine is unable to disambiguate between the two routes and will always pick the first one obviously.

Comment: I have tested your route suggestion with default and it's not worked, after i have deleted the default route , it did worked.

Comment: It's normal that it doesn't work with the default route. The reason for that is because they are conflicting and incompatible. You could use route constraints. For example if you know that `{page}` will always be an integer and `{id}` always a string you could use the following regex route constraint: `page=@"\d+"`. To understand more about routing checkout the following article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, as soon as possible i will sign your answer as an answer.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you show an example of two constraints , the default one and mine?

Comment: I don't know what are your requirements. For example if you have ids that can contain only [a-z] characters and your page numbers are only integers you could have 2 routes: `context.MapRoute("Admin_default", "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, new { id = @"[a-z]*" }); context.MapRoute("Admin_page", "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{page}", new { action = "Index" }, new { page = @"\d+" } );`. But it will all depend on your exact application requirements.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11149/discussion-between-iamstalker-and-darin-dimitrov)